# Add lines to SVG donut

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am working on creating a donut graph like this:

[image: donut graph that I wanted to achieve]

And this is the graph that I have from my JSFiddle.

```
var τ = 2 * Math.PI,
        width = 100,
        height = 100,
        outerRadius = Math.min(width,height)/2,
        innerRadius = (outerRadius/5)*4,
        fontSize = (Math.min(width,height)/4);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius)
    .cornerRadius(outerRadius - innerRadius)
    .startAngle(0);

var svg = d3.select('.chart-container').append("svg")
    .attr("width", '100%')
    .attr("height", '100%')
    .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height) +' '+Math.min(width,height) )
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + "," + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + ")");

var text = svg.append("text")
    .text('0%')
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font-size",fontSize+'px')
    .attr("dy",fontSize/3)
    .attr("dx",2);

var background = svg.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: τ})
    .style("fill", "#7cc35f")
    .attr("d", arc);

var midground = svg.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: 0 * τ})
    .style("fill", "lightblue")
    .attr("d", arc);

var foreground = svg.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: 0 * τ})
    .style("fill", "#57893e")
    .attr("d", arc);

midground.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(arcTween, 0.49 * τ);

foreground.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(arcTween, 0.25 * τ);

function arcTween(transition, newAngle) {

    transition.attrTween("d", function(d) {

        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);

        return function(t) {

            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);

            text.text(Math.round((d.endAngle/τ)*100)+'%');

            return arc(d);
        };
    });
}
```

I do not know how to add the four black lines to separate the quarters of the donut. Can anyone give me some insights on how to achieve that?

Comment: can you please provide a JSFiddle link?

Comment: i made an example from your code: https://jsfiddle.net/2c7ajn8t/1/

Comment: Thank you @XzenTorXz, thanks for the jsfiddle and the working example you had provided. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pure D3 approach would use something like this:

```
svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(d3.range(0, 360, 90))
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("y1", outerRadius)
    .attr("y2", innerRadius)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + d + ")"});
```

Use [`d3.range()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#range) to create the array of values at which your marks should be placed. For this example this could also be written as `[0, 90, 180, 270]`, but using `d3.range()` you could easily customize the number of marks to be placed around the perimeter of your donut by adjusting the step denoted by the third parameter. After binding the array, use the enter selection to append the lines to your chart. These require setting only `y1` and `y2` with `x1` and `x2` defaulting to `0` as the lines are afterwards rotated to their destination according to the bound values.

Have a look at this working example:

```js
 var τ = 2 * Math.PI,
        width = 100,
        height = 100,
        outerRadius = Math.min(width,height)/2,
        innerRadius = (outerRadius/5)*4,
        fontSize = (Math.min(width,height)/4);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius)
    .cornerRadius(outerRadius - innerRadius)
    .startAngle(0);

var svg = d3.select('.chart-container').append("svg")
    .attr("width", '100%')
    .attr("height", '100%')
    .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height) +' '+Math.min(width,height) )
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + "," + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + ")");

var text = svg.append("text")
    .text('0%')
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font-size",fontSize+'px')
    .attr("dy",fontSize/3)
    .attr("dx",2);

var background = svg.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: τ})
    .style("fill", "#7cc35f")
    .attr("d", arc);

var midground = svg.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: 0 * τ})
    .style("fill", "lightblue")
    .attr("d", arc);

var foreground = svg.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: 0 * τ})
    .style("fill", "#57893e")
    .attr("d", arc);
    
midground.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(arcTween, 0.49 * τ);

foreground.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(arcTween, 0.25 * τ);

svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(d3.range(0, 360, 90))
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("y1", outerRadius)
    .attr("y2", innerRadius)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + d + ")"});
    
function arcTween(transition, newAngle) {

    transition.attrTween("d", function(d) {

        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);

        return function(t) {

            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);

            text.text(Math.round((d.endAngle/τ)*100)+'%');

            return arc(d);
        };
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to calculate and draw the line:

```
 var drawDonutLine = function(angle, overlap){
    var overlap = overlap || 0;
    angle = angle / (180 / Math.PI);
    var innerR = (innerRadius-overlap);
    var outerR = (outerRadius+overlap);

    var beginX = Math.sin(angle)*innerR
    var beginY = -Math.cos(angle)*innerR;
    var endX = Math.sin(angle)*outerR;
    var endY = -Math.cos(angle)*outerR;
    svg.append('path')
      .datum({})
      .style("fill", "#000")
      .attr('stroke', 'black')
      .attr('stroke-width', 5)
      .attr('d', "M "+beginX+" "+beginY+" L "+endX+" "+endY)
    ;       
}
```

and use it like, where the first parameter is the angle (in degree), and the second parameter the overlapping in px

```
drawDonutLine(0,5);
```

see working example https://jsfiddle.net/2c7ajn8t/3/

I used https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js as reference